How can you prove directly that two polynomials with only real roots can make a polynomial that has complex roots with addition?
Generally, if a polynomial over the real numbers of degree $n$ has $n$ roots then it means that it only has real roots.
I found an example where when I add two of these polynomial, I get one with a complex root.
$$g_1(x)=x^2; g_2(x)=1$$
$$g_1(x)+g_2(x)=x^2+1$$
$x^2 + 1$ only has complex roots so this a proof by contradiction. But how would I prove it directly?

This is a direct proof, at least as written.

This is not a proof by contradiction. To prove that something exists, you only have to provide an example of such a thing. This is as direct a proof as you can get!

Working backwards, what do you mean by "prove it directly" ? A mathematical truth must be true all of the time to be true, not some of the time. Even one counterexample is enough of a "direct" proof, not a proof by contradiction. Secondly, $g_2(x)=1$ has no roots at all! There is a subtle distinction lost here - not having complex roots does not equate to having all of the roots be real. Thirdly, the first thing you say "generally..." is not even true in the first place.

I see, I thought using a counter example would mean contradiction.

It's not a counter-example, it's just an example.

Should I change the question or delete it? I don't really know what to do.

The question has a resolution since you figured out there was something flawed with the logic. You shouldn't delete it in case someone in the future has the same mistake as you.
